# why does $.each() not work with arrays that have a string index in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

version a:

```js
var x = [];
x['abc'] = 'd';
x['xyz'] = 'abbb';
$.each(x, function(i, el) {
  console.error(el);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

does not work. No output in console see here:

How can I make version a work?

Comment: That's not an array with string indexes. It's an array with two properties that you have tacked onto it. The length is still 0. If you want to iterate through the properties, you can use `Object.keys(x)`.

Comment: Don't use an array for this. Use an object: `var x = {}`

Comment: how is that a duplicate?..... This is a common pitfall.

Comment: You can simply use for-in:
for(var _x in x){
 console.log(_x,":",x[_x]);
}

Comment: @Toskan Um, it's a duplicate _because_ it's a common pitfall.

Comment: @JLRishe have a lolly, you are a good boy

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

> Arrays and array-like objects with a `length` property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via their named properties.

Since `x` is an array, only its numeric properties are considered, not its named properties. Since it doesn't have any of these, nothing is printed.

You make it work by using an object instead of an array.

```js
var x = {};
x['abc'] = 'd';
x['xyz'] = 'abbb';
$.each(x, function(i, el) {
  console.error(el);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an associative array in javascript. We have objects. Your current code using an object instead of an array should do the trick.

```js
var x = {};  // Note that we're using curly brances
x["abc"] = 123;
x["def"] = 456;

$.each(x, function(key, value){
   console.log(key, value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: so what exactly did I do to my array?

Comment: Use an object instead. `{}` instead of `[]`.